# Framework of choice for building smart histogram in cocoa touch

Tags: cocoa-touch, plot, core-graphics, histogram, binning

I'm familiar with the basics of objective-c and cocoa touch and I want to start now my first large iOS project.

I want to build an iPad app with a histogram like you know it from several photo apps where you can see e.g. the distribution of brightness in a picture. But it needs to be smart, i.e. scrolling horizontal, setting borders and pinching for zoom-in and zoom-out.

Is it possible to handle this requirements with iOS7 standard API or do I need a 3rd party framework like [Core-Plot](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot) to achieve a histogram I described, and if so, which one would you prefer and why.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to handle this requirements with iOS7 standard API or do I need a 3rd party framework

It's certainly *possible* to do it all yourself with no help from anybody except the frameworks that Apple provides. Whether that's the best solution for you, only you can decide. I think these are the relevant considerations:

- You seem to have some fairly specific requirements and it sounds like you may need fairly fine control over exactly how this histogram looks and works. These are good reasons to create the histogram yourself.
- You're still fairly new to Objective-C, Cocoa Touch, etc. That's a good reason to look for something that's already written. You'll save a lot of time and frustration, but you may have to be a little more flexible in terms of what you're willing to accept; it's unlikely that anybody has already written *exactly* the thing you want.

I'd suggest taking a shot a building what you want, and if it turns out to be a bigger thing than you're ready to tackle, you'll at least have a better understanding of what's involved.

To get started, read up on `UIBezierPath`. All you really need to do is to create a view that accepts an array of numbers and draws the corresponding graph. Don't worry about zooming and scrolling yet, just make a view that draws the graph. Once you have that, you can read up on `UIScrollView`, which will give you the scrolling and zooming with almost no work.

Comment: Thx Caleb. Your suggestion definitely make sense.